# How to import opencv project into android

Tags: opencv, android-ndk, android

so, I m a bit confused here. I have an opencv project which import an image and does something with it and gives output.So I want to use this project as one part in my android project.So how do I proceed. I have SDK, NDK openCV lib all installed. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Compile your project with NDK as a static library.
2. Create a shared library with JNI entry point that takes the necessary inputs from Java and return the result to Java. Link it with your static lib and OpenCV.
3. Create a Java Android project that uses this shared library.

Comment: thnx gonna give this a try